# how to parse json (nested) from url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I create website to buy and sell cars. I used Edmunds API to get car information.

I tried to parse information into drop list  from their API site as JSON format but I did not get result . I do not how to get information from nested arrays 
how to get name, nickName , year (in the image)?

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<select id="dd"></select>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?state=used&year=2014&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }

}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var items = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";



    function addOptions(){
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        var jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("url");
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
        option = document.createElement('option');
              option.text = jsonArray.makes[0].name;
              select.add(option);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scKIY.png)

Comment: Are you missing some code? that isn't valid JS... You also never call `addOptions()`, you never loop over `items`... it seems like some code is missing.

Comment: Related: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close `addOptions()` and his `for` loop inside's brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrTest = items.makes;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrTest.length; i++) {


                var oneObj = arrTest[i];

                var strName = oneObj.name;
                var niceName = oneObj.niceName;

                var arrModel = oneObj.models;

                for (var j = 0; j < arrModel.length; j++) {

                    var strName1 = arrModel[j].name;
                    var niceName1 = arrModel[j].niceName;
                      debugger; 
                    var arrYear = arrModel[j].years[0];
                }
            }
```

You can loop `arrModel[j].nickName[0].year` if there are multiple elements

Comment: Thanks.When i print strName or any var I will get undefined except arrTest

Comment: Please print oneObj and see what is the value

Comment: undefined  also. if I print arrTest I will get [object Object]

Comment: Please add sample json that you shared in image

Comment: {
    "makes": [
        {
            "id": 200002038,
            "name": "Acura",
            "niceName": "acura",
            "models": [
                {
                    "id": "Acura_ILX",
                    "name": "ILX",
                    "niceName": "ilx",
                    "years": [
                        {
                            "id": 200471908,
                            "year": 2014
                        }
                    ]
                },